# Backup local Git repository (notes, stashes, reflog included) and restore it on another machine

Tags: git, migration, backup, git-stash, git-reflog

As in the title, **how can I backup completely a local Git repository and its state**, restore it on another machine, and have the new repository to be in the exact state as the one on the previous machine?

I mainly care to not loose local stuff, like:

- stashes (that's the most important thing)
- reflog (I want to keep my operations history)
- notes
- all the rest (possibly)

**EDIT**

I already tried to compress my local directory, including hidden files like `.git`, and restore it on the other machine.

What I get, after that, with `git status` is:

- **a HUGE list of changed files** (and I don't recognize the changes)
- **the repository is in a *detached HEAD***

If everything is in the `.git` folder, why I get the HEAD detached and I don't get the same pointing of the old repository?

And what are all these modified/deleted/typechanged files?

It seems that `.git` is not really taking **everything** from the old repository.

Comment: You did something wrong when compressing and restoring. Detached HEAD or not is stored in a simple text file `.git/HEAD`, it's not a state that you may lose by copying to another machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you copy/paste your whole directory from one machine to the other (including hidden files like `.git`, ...), you will be keeping:

- stashes (that's the most important thing)
- all your history, including all local branches, ...
- notes

Git always stores the data of one repository inside the `.git` repository, and nowhere else

Comment: Yeah I was trying that but I asked because I got the result that I explained in the **EDIT** of my original question. There are effects that I cannot explain; and that doesn't assure me that everything went wrong; I suspect something else could have changed.